# Redirect to protected route after user login its not working - Angular app

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I been following an Angular tutorial and I was able to make it work so far, but my app its not redirecting the user after login into any of the pages with the "canActivate [AuthGuard]" option enabled, I even tried clicking to any of the "canActivate [AuthGuard]" after login in and it doesn't change anything, not the URL, not the page, if I take of the "canActivate [AuthGuard]" I'm able to navigate to it through the drop down menu and all.

Please help me find the problem.

I uploaded my project so far in to my github profile so that you can take a look at the code, the files related to this functionality are "app.module.ts", "app.component.ts", "auth-guard.service.ts" and "auth.service.ts".

https://github.com/jsalcedoa/oShop

Comment: Probably not a good idea to upload your environment files to github if they contain sensitive information like api keys.

Comment: Also, I don't see any routes in your app-routing module. Is the latest version of your code in the repo? You might be better off recreating the problem with minimal code in a stackblitz.

Comment: Hi @KurtHamilton the code for the routes are inside "app.module.ts". I will consider your advise of not uploading my development environment files to GitHub for the future, the good thing its this is just an example I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

It's not redirecting after login becuase you're not telling it to.

Your auth service login method needs to return the result of the method that's already in there. It's probably a promise or an observable. This will allow the login component to know when the login response comes back and behave appropriately.

If the login response is successful, then you need to navigate to whatever page is appropriate. In this case it's either the return url you are currently getting in the service, or a route of your choosing.

**login component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
    // inject Router and ActivatedRoute into components, not services
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { 
  }

  login() {
    // assuming promise will be returned from auth service
    // TODO: handle errors and display login error - out of scope for this question
    this.auth.login()
      .then(message => {
        // moved from auth service
        const returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
        // now do the navigation
        this.router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
      });
  }
}
```

**auth service**

```
login(): Promise<string> {
  // I'm assuming that this is a promise that returns a message 
  // for the purposes of demonstrating the general login pattern.
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}
```